# Extracting words from a sentence in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I have table and the table 'test' and it has column filename whilch contains differnt format of sentences.

```
filename                                                
LA West Employer us Rort October 2015.txt201510         
LA loyer sus Rrt April 2017         
LA oyer sus Rept April 2018.txt201712               
LA oyer sus Ret April 2019.txt201712                
LA Eoyer sus Ret Aug 2019.txt201712             
LA oyer sus Rort August 2017(2).txt201708           
LA Eyer sus Rort August 2018 (1).txt201712      
LA Eyer sus Reort Dec 2017.txt201711                
LA Emyer sus Report Dec 2018 (1).txt201712  
LA Emyer sus Report October- 2018 (1).txt201712
```

My expected output is:

```
October 2015
April 2017
Aug 2019
Dec 2017
```

Each row is containing Month year, I want to extract that part from it.

I tried as below:

```
SELECT
SubStr(filename,INSTR(filename,'Report')+7,(INSTR(filename,'(')-1)-(INSTR(filename,'Report')+7))res
FROM test ;

select regexp_substr(filename, '[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]][^[:space:]]+$') from table;
```

It didnot worked.How I can achieve this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is:

```
select replace(regexp_substr('LLC Emyer sus Report October- 2018 (1).txt201712', '[[:alpha:]-]+[[:space:]][[:digit:]]{4}'), '-', '')
  from dual;
```

Comment: Try this version: replace(regexp_substr('LLC Emyer sus Report October- 2018 (1).txt201712', '[[:alpha:]-]+[[:space:]][[:digit:]]{4}'), '-', '')

Comment: ok thank you your code worked for me, can u please explain me what these regular expression does?

Comment: The expression looks for 1 or more letters or - character, after this there is a whitespace character, and 4 digits at the end.

Answer (score 0):

This pattern also works fine

```sql
select FILENAME, regexp_substr(FILENAME, '([[:alpha:]]+\s+[[:digit:]]+)\s*(\([[:digit:]]+\))?\.txt.+?$', 1, 1, 'i', 1) expected_output
from your_table
```